# iterate over list of dicts to find minimum values per unique value

Tags: python-3.8

I am looking for the minimum of 'diff' per unique 'expiry' in the following list of dicts. Guessing `itertools.groupby` can help but really lost how to apply that.

```
import datetime as dt

data = [ {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,6,26), 'strike': 138.0, 'diff': 0.305}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,6,26), 'strike': 138.5, 'diff': 0.188}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,6,26), 'strike': 139.0, 'diff': 0.688}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,7,24), 'strike': 137.0, 'diff': 0.805},
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,7,24), 'strike': 137.5, 'diff': 0.305}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,7,24), 'strike': 138.0, 'diff': 0.203}, 
        {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,7,24), 'strike': 138.5, 'diff': 0.703}]
```

desired output:

```
[{'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,6,26), 'strike': 138.5, 'diff': 0.188},
{'expiry': dt.datetime(2020,7,24), 'strike': 138.0, 'diff': 0.203}]
```

Looking for an efficient and fast way to solve this (without using pandas).

Answer (score 0):

```
m = dict()
for d in data:
  m.update({
    d['expiry']: min(
      d['diff'], m[d['expiry']] if d['expiry'] in m else d['diff']
    )
  })
for exp, min_of_diff in m.items():
  print('{},{}'.format(exp,min_of_diff))
```

or if you want access to the whole dict:

```
m = dict()
for d in data:
  if d['expiry'] not in m:
    m.update({
      d['expiry']: d
    })
    continue
  # otherwise, get the lesser
  smallest_diff = m[d['expiry']]['diff']
  if d['diff'] < smallest_diff:
    m.update({
      d['expiry']: d
    })
for exp, min_dict in m.items():
  print('{},{}'.format(exp,min_dict))
```

I haven't tested these solutions.
But that should give you the idea.

Comment: Note that you should not assume the 'diff' column has a unique minimum. Depending on your use case, you may need a tie break to ensure you consistently pick the same dict.

Comment: and you can just do comparison instead of ```min()``` if you might have ```None```s in there... I recall min and max can do odd things when None types are compared...

Comment: Thanks, the first solution works but I do indeed need to get the whole dict. The solution for that throws a KeyError: 'expiry'

Comment: @steff sorry, I had a mistake in the second option. I've corrected (without testing) and also made it more readable. Hopefully you can figure it out from here...